# How to create nested scrollview in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nested, scrollview

I need two vertical scrollviews in a screen. Outer scroll should stop scrolling when it reaches a particular point.(tilte of the page reaches at the top). When outer scroll stopped scrolling, inner scrollview should start scrolling. How can I get this working?

[image]

Comment: Putting one inside the other should work as you want. You can do it either by code or by interface builder.